# dropdown option select in register form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a register form with a dropdown select option.
The register form is:

Name:
Email:
Password:
School: (dropdown option list)
I have set up two table, one called "users", the other "schools".
In my "users" table, the columns are `"id"(int(11))`, `"email"(varchar(255)`, `"name"(varchar(64)`, and "school"(varchar (64)).
In my "schools" table, the columns are "id"(int(11)), "users_id"(int(11)), and "school_id"(int(11))". I'm not sure if this table's setup is correct, so please tell me if there is a better way of setting it up. I made the "school_id" as I also later will have a search system where users can search for people in specific schools.

So far the form part of my register.html:

```
 <form action="register.php" method="post">
    <div class="field">
       <label for="email">Email:</label>
       <input type="email" id="email" value="" autocomplete="on" action="" />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
       <label for="password">Password:</label><br />
       <input type="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
       <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
       <input type="text" id="name" action="" />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
       <label for="school">School:</label>
       <select id="school" size="1">
          <option value="a">Apple School</option>
          <option value="b">Banana School</option>
          <option value="c">Carrot School</option>
       </select>
    </div>    

    <input name="Register" type="submit" id="register" value="" />
 </form>
```

And my register.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
   if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'email' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 255,
            'unique' => 'users'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
//I don't know how to put the school drop down in here)
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $salt = Hash::salt(32);

        try {
            $user->create(array(
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                'salt' => $salt,
                'name' => Input::get('name'),
                'school' => Input::get('school'),
                'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ));

            Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now log in!');
            Redirect::to('index.php'); 

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
}?>
```

If there are other ways to do this, please help me. I found this way through the OOP Login/register tutorial from phpacademy.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ??

Comment: Is this running on any framework ?

Comment: not getting any errors, i'm asking how to code the drop down option list into this coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your table in this format

**User Table**

`"id"(int(11))`, `"email"(varchar(255)`, `"name"(varchar(64)`, and `"school_id"(int(11))`

**School Table**

`"id"(int(11))`,`"school_id"(int(11))"`, and `"school_name"(varchar(255))`

Now you can access the school table to put the drop down in your code.

Comment: should I use auto_increment for id in school table (as I did for users) and for school_id?

Comment: 1. Yes, you should make school (id auto_increment). 2. If you want to assign some specific id to school then you can use `school_id` otherwise you can just ignore `school_id`

Comment: it shows 'Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key" when I try to autoincrement the school_id. What should I do?

Comment: No you don't need to make it auto_increment you just need to fill this value manually otherwise remove it and use School table `id` as school id in user table

Comment: do you mean remove it from the users table? but if i do that, how will the data from the register form be added into it?